# Best approach to Quantile Vector Autoregression

Tags: regression, time-series, vector-autoregression, quantile-regression, endogeneity

So I have a system of endogenous variables in panel form (24 Stock over 52 weeks). I would like to use quantile regression of one variable (Trading Volume) upon another (Social Media Sentiment). The literature has used VAR, however, I was hoping to explore the relationship at the quantile level, although the endogeneity issue would prevent me from using a regular quantile panel regression without some previous treatment. I have explored some literature regarding quantile VAR although I am somewhat lost on how to implement this in practice and was wondering if any libraries/packages exist for this in R/STATA/Python etc..?

Comment: What did you use in the end?